# How to remove all children of a static shape on stage?

Tags: arrays, loops, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am making a projectile motion simulation, and one of the options involves the use of a graph function.

So when I press the Graph button (button_2), the graph template layer is visible. There is a pre-calculated array with the coordinates of the values which must be plotted on the graph.

For every coordinate (per 0.1 seconds, as indicated by the countdown timer), a movie-clip 'point' is placed there. A new circle shape is then created and placed on the same point (copying its coordinates). Thus, the stage now has a parabolic dotted line. However, when pressing the 'back' button, all the created circles do not disappear/reset (removing all children) as intended.

I tried to use a loop function which removes all children, but I keep getting error messages.

```
button_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToGraph);

function goToGraph(event:MouseEvent):void
{

graphTemplate.visible = true;
backToSim1.visible = true;
point.visible = true;

point.x = 42
point.y = 608

var vx = velocity*Math.cos(angle/(180/Math.PI));
var vy = velocity*Math.sin(angle/(180/Math.PI));
var Time = int(((2*vy)/9.81)*100)/100

if (Time != 0) {


    var t :Number = 0;
    var position:Array = new Array();
    var pos_idx :int = 0; //the position within the array


    while(t <= Time)
    {
        position[ pos_idx ] = (vy * t) - 4.905 * (t * t);
        trace("position[" + pos_idx + "]: " + position[ pos_idx ] );

        t += 0.1;
        t = Number( t.toFixed(3) ); 
        trace("t is: " + t);

        pos_idx += 1; 
    }



    var fl_TimerInstance:Timer = new Timer(100, (Time*10));
    fl_TimerInstance.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fl_TimerHandler);
    fl_TimerInstance.start();
    var a = 0;
    var timeElapsed = 0;


    function fl_TimerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
    {
        a = a+1;



        point.x = point.x + (vx*1.2);
        point.y = 608 - (position[a]*10);
        timeElapsed = timeElapsed + 1;

        var circle:Shape = new Shape();
        circle.graphics.clear();
        circle.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x000000);
        circle.graphics.beginFill(0x990000);
        circle.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,1);
        circle.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(circle);
        circle.x = point.x
        circle.y = point.y


        if (position[a+1] == null) {
            point.visible = false;

            }

    }

}

    backToSim1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToHide_2);

    function fl_ClickToHide_2(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
    graphTemplate.visible = false;
    backToSim1.visible = false;
    point.visible = false;

    while (circle.numChildren > 0) {
    circle.removeChildAt(0);
    }


    }

}
```

I get the following errors:

- Access of possibly undefined property numChildren through a reference with static type flash.display:Shape.
- Call to a possibly undefined method removeChildAt through a reference with static type flash.display:Shape.

I expect all the created 'circle' variables to be reset/deleted. How can I do that?

Comment: Runtime drawings are not display children of the object. You should remove all **circle**s, not children from the last **circle** object.

Comment: That makes sense. So, how would I be able to remove them all? As in accessing these circles and removing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways how to structurize the picture. Personally I'd go for **Array** solution, but your code is messy (bad formatting, functions inside functions) so resorting to names it is.

```
var Circles:Array = new Array;

function fl_TimerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    // ...

    var circle:Shape = new Shape();

    circle.name = "Circle";

    // ...
}

function fl_ClickToHide_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // ...

    for (var i:int = numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var aChild:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);

        if (aChild.name == "Circle")
        {
            removeChildAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I'll try to organize my code a little more as well in the future, so thanks for the feedback.